# How to iterate through a directory and read in 2 files at each iteration using pathlib.Path().glob()

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, glob, pathlib

Using pathlib.Path().glob(), how do we iterate through a directory and read in 2 files at each iteration?

Suppose my directory `C:\Users\server\Desktop\Dataset` looks like this:

```
P1_mean_fle.csv
P2_mean_fle.csv
P3_mean_fle.csv
P1_std_dev_fle.csv
P2_std_dev_fle.csv
P3_std_dev_fle.csv
```

If I want to read in only 1 file at each iteration of the Pi's, my code would look like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\server\Desktop\Dataset'
param_file = 'P*' + '_mean_fle.csv'

for i, fle in enumerate(Path(file_path).glob(param_file)):
    mean_fle = pd.read_csv(fle).values

    results = tuning(mean_fle)  #tuning is some function which takes in the file mean 
                                #and does something with this file
```

Now, how I do read in 2 files at each iteration of the Pi's? The code below doesn't quite work because `param_file` can only be assigned with one file name type. Would appreciate if there is a way to do this using `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

param_file = 'P*' + '_mean_fle.csv'
param_file = 'P*' + '_std_dev_fle.csv'  #this is wrong

for i, fle in enumerate(Path(file_path).glob(param_file)):  #this is wrong inside the glob() part
    mean_fle = pd.read_csv(fle).values
    std_dev_fle = pd.read_csv(fle).values

    results = tuning(mean_fle, std_dev_fle)  #tuning is some function which takes in the two files mean 
                                             #and std_dev and does something with these 2 files
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your filenames follow deterministic rules as in the example, your best bet is to iterate one kind of files, and find the corresponding file by string replacement.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\server\Desktop\Dataset'
param_file = 'P*' + '_mean_fle.csv'

for i, fle in enumerate(Path(file_path).glob(param_file)):
    stddev_fle = fle.with_name(fle.name.replace("mean", "std_dev"))
    mean_values = pd.read_csv(fle).values
    stddev_values = pd.read_csv(stddev_fle).values

    results = tuning(mean_values, stddev_values)
```

Comment: Hi @Torben Klein, should the `fle.name.replace("mean", "std_dev")` here be `fle.name.replace("_mean_fle.csv", "_std_dev_fle.csv")`?

Comment: Both would work. ``replace`` searches for the given text and replaces it by the second text. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you two approaches:

1.

If you are sure that you have all your files without 'holes' in numbering, you can just take them without 'glob':

```
mean_csv_pattern = 'P{}_mean_fle.csv'
std_dev_pattern = 'P{}_std_dev_fle.csv'

i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    try:
        mean_fle = pd.read_csv(mean_csv_pattern.format(i)).values
        std_dev_fle = pd.read_csv(std_dev_pattern.format(i)).values
    except (<put your exceptions here>):
        break
    results = tuning(mean_fle, std_dev_fle)
```

2.

Use a pre-fetch operation that takes all your files and put them in a structure that you can query in your main loop.

Glob for mean files, glob for std_dev files, take the number from the filename and biuld a dictionary {index: {'mean_file': mean_file, 'std_file': std_file)}
and then loop over sorted dictionary keys...

Comment: Thanks @Don, this is a good alternative to glob(). Can I ask what do you mean by 'holes' here?

Comment: @Leockl, I mean the you have to be sure to have all files from 1 on: if you have file 1, 2 and 4, the loop will stop when trying to get file '3'